# How to print associated data in the index view

Tags: php, html, css, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

```
$subjects = $this->Subjects
    ->find('all', [
        'contain'=> [
            'Users'
        ],
        'fields'=> [
            'Users.username',
            'Users.email'
        ]
    ])
    ->hydrate(false)
    ->toArray();

$this->set('subjects', $subjects);
```

how can i loop the data in the INDEX view of Subjects controller to display like this image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample Result from your vardump :

```
<?php
$array = array(
    0 => array(
        'math'=>40,
        'english'=>40,
        'history'=>40,
        'science'=>40,
        'user_id'=>64
        'user'=>
            array(
            'id' => 6
            'name' => 'User',
            'email' => 'user1@sample.com'
            )
    )
);
?>
```

This is the sample code writing based on the vardump you provided:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    /// Give your table headers
    </thead>
<tbody>
    <?php foreach($subjects as $subject) :?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$subject['math']?></td>
            <td><?=$subject['english']?></td>
            <td><?=$subject['history']?></td>
            <td><?=$subject['science']?></td>
            <td><?=$subject['user_id']?></td>
            <td><?=$subject['user']['id']?></td>
            <td><?=$subject['user']['name']?></td>
            <td><?=$subject['user']['email']?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: can you post your query? Are you retrieving id and user_id? id and user_id are from which table?

Comment: see image for the query https://ibb.co/mZ0QP5      id is from users table and user_id is in subjects table

Comment: id and user_id have the same value in the code u suggested, original value https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vHGN.png

Comment: But in the given image they are different

Comment: what image you mean?  this is the original data i query in command line  https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vHGN.png

Comment: ahh, this is what you mean, in var dump, how is it happen, they have same value the id and user_id, is my query lacking? or do i need to add in relationship in the 2 tables

Answer (score 1):

I tested it. E.g This is your subject array.

```
<?php
$array = array(
    0 => array(
        'Users'=>
        array('name' => 'John Doe',
        'email' => 'john@example.com'
        )
    ),
    1 => array(
        'Users'=>array(
        'name' => 'Abs Doe',
        'email' => 'jane@example.com'
        )
    ),
);
?>
```

This is loop in your index file.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>email</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($array as $subject) :?>
            <tr>
                <td><?=$subject['Users']['name']?></td>
                <td><?=$subject['Users']['email']?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It's worked as expected.

[image]

I can not give you answer. Because, I don't have access to your environment. But, at least you can get idea which code need amend. 
Hope this help.

Comment: what i missed?  this is the error  Notice (8): Undefined variable: array [APP/Template\Subjects\index.ctp, line 27]
Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP/Template\Subjects\index.ctp, line 27]

Comment: This is test array. You need to replace with your array.

Comment: I replace the araay with $subjects <?php foreach($subjects  as $subject) :?>
            <tr>
                
               
                <td><?=$subject['Users']['username']?></td>
                <td><?=$subject['Users']['email']?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach;?>           Undefined index: Users [APP/Template\Subjects\index.ctp, line 29,line30,line31,line32 and so on

Comment: try var_dump in view file to $subjects. Then, update your question with printed result. That's will helpful.

Comment: it will display all the details of the array and the value  see image https://ibb.co/kKas45

Comment: So, some are need to print `<?=$subject['user']['name']?>` and some are need to print `<?=$subject['math']?>`. The things is you didn't provide detail and we blindly helping to you. Please don't copy and paste from sample answer.

Comment: <td><?=$subject['User']['user_id']?></td>
                <td><?=$subject['User']['username']?></td>
                <td><?=$subject['User']['email']?></td>     Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: thank you so much @kevin Kyaw , can i add you in skype

Answer (score 0):

Do play some css first. Hopefully, this code snippet can help you.

You need to do some changes in this.

```
'fields'=> [
        'Users.username',
        'Users.email',
        //add more fields that you want to display here
]



<table>
    <thead>
         <th>math</th>
         <th>english</th>
         <th>history</th>
         <th>science</th>
         <th>id</th>
         <th>user_id</th>
         <th>username</th>
         <th>email</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($subjects as $subject) :?>
            <tr>
                <td><?=$subject['Users']['match']?></td>
                <td><?=$subject['Users']['english']?></td>
                <td><?=$subject['Users']['history']?></td>
                <td><?=$subject['Users']['science']?></td>
                <td><?=$subject['Users']['id']?></td>
                <td><?=$subject['Users']['user_id']?></td>
                <td><?=$subject['Users']['username']?></td>
                <td><?=$subject['Users']['email']?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but still will not print the username and email

Comment: Meaning, you can print other fields?

Comment: remember  username and email fields is in the users table, yes all the data will print except the username and email

Comment: Can you change to `'fields'=> ['Users.*']`.  How about `var_dump` in your controller to `$subjects`?

Comment: Please try <?=$subject['Users']['username']?>

Comment: @KevinKyaw  it will display all including the username and email when var_dump($subjects); if i change also the fields to 'fields'=> ['Users.*']  error on sql syntax..

Comment: @ViniApp still the username and emaill will not print

Comment: @ViniApp   <?php foreach($subjects as $subject) :?>
            <tr>
                <td><?=$subject['math']?></td>
                <td><?=$subject['english']?></td>
                <td><?=$subject['history']?></td>
                <td><?=$subject['science']?></td>
                <td><?=$subject['id']?></td>
                <td><?=$subject['user_id']?></td>
                <td> <?=$subject['Users']['username']?> </td>
                <td><?=$subject['email']?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach;?>

Comment: Check updated answer. But, you need to amend your query too. You just selected only two fields in your query such as email and username only. You need to add other fields that you want to display in view file.