# How to print the data with the relation hasMany relationship?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

UsersTable.php

public function initialize(array $config)
    {

```
    parent::initialize($config);
    $this->belongsTo('Users');
    $this->hasMany('Subjects');
    $this->table('users');       

    $this->displayField('username');  
    $this->primaryKey('id'); 
}
```

[image]

how to print data including from other table like  I did on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45971640/how-to-print-associated-data-in-the-index-view/45972953)  I want to display all the subjects with grades in users table

*** view.ctp***** in users

```
<div class="actions columns large-2 medium-3">
    <h3><?= __('Actions') ?></h3>
    <ul class="side-nav">
        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('Edit User'), ['action' => 'edit', $users->id]) ?> </li>
        <li><?= $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete User'), ['action' => 'delete', $user->id], ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $user->id)]) ?> </li>
        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('List Users'), ['action' => 'index']) ?> </li>
        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('New User'), ['action' => 'add']) ?> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="users view large-10 medium-9 columns">
<?php   

foreach ($users as $user): ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-5 columns strings">
            <h6 class="subheader"><?= __('Username') ?></h6>
            <p><?= h($user->username) ?></p>

        </div>
        <div class="large-2 columns numbers end">
            <h6 class="subheader"><?= __('Id') ?></h6>
            <p><?= $this->Number->format($user->id) ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and how is the result you're getting different from the desired result? Stack Overflow isn't for writing your code for you, it's for helping you to fix problems with your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Also, have you gone through the CakePHP tutorial? It covers this sort of thing. Also, if you use the bake tool that comes with Cake, it should generate all of this code for you, and you can just adjust the details to match your requirements, instead of having to write it all from scratch.

Comment: YES, I use bake tool @GregSchmidt my question is the continuation, please click the link above highlited by blue, in that question the already answered I can already print associated data from users table in subjects view,    but now i want also vice versa, in users view i want to print the data related in subjects table.

Comment: Okay, it's just that, if your database was already set up this way, bake would have generated a model that creates the correct associations, a controller that includes them when reading the record, and a user view that would include all of the code to do what you're asking. Since you haven't shown us any of either the controller or view code, we have no way to know what's going wrong here.

Comment: hi @GregSchmidt, I already added the view code in my users table

Comment: If you baked this, there should be a "related" div after what you've shown here, which would include a `foreach` loop over `$user->subjects`. Hard to say what's gone wrong for you. Did you delete that section? Did you add the `user_id` column to the subjects table after you baked?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to tell you, that only subjects tables I used bake command tools, I also edit the code in the view.ctp the complete code..  how can I do this now?

Comment: You can use bake at any time to bake an individual model, controller or templates. It will need to overwrite files that you have there right now (it asks for confirmation, but doesn't give an option to save it elsewhere), so copy or move them to somewhere safe first, if there's anything that you need to save in them.

Comment: do i need also to set up reference from table users and table subjects? in order in bake command it will directly set up the association?

Comment: Not quite clear what you're asking here. Bake will bake whatever you ask it to bake. If you have it bake the model, it will create the association. But it looks like the association is already there (though not sure why the users table is also associated to itself).